# Writing Number Outputs to Array

Tags: c, arrays, output

How would I go about putting numbers that have been calculated and enter them into an array?
For instance if I have the functions:

```
int sum_even ( int p1, int p3, int p5, int p7, int p9, int p11){
even_total = array_1[1] + array_1[3] + array_1[5] + array_1[7] + array_1[9] + array_1[11];
printf("The sum of the even numbers: %d\n", even_total);
return;
}

int sum_odd (int p2, int p4, int p6, int p8, int p10, int p12){
odd_total = array_1[0] + array_1[2] + array_1[4] + array_1[6] + array_1[8] + array_1[10] + array_1[12];
printf( "The sum of the odd numbers: %d\n", odd_total);
return;
}

int total (int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5, int p6, int p7, int p8, int p9, int p10, p11, p12){
total_all = odd_total + even_total;
printf( "The total of the numbers is: %d\n", total_all);
return;
}
```

Now say the total of the even and odd numbers (total_all) is 18. How would I split them up so that array_2[1] is 1 and array_2[2] is 8?

Comment: The total of even and odd is `18`. **How can the sum of the `array_1` and `array_2` be `1` and `8` respectively?**

Comment: @jrd1 Maybe he wants to split the digits of 18 into 1 and 8?

Comment: @Patashu, I have no idea!

Comment: I do because I need to take the last digit if it not a zero and subtract 10 from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now say the total of the even and odd numbers (total_all) is 18. How would I split them up so that array_2[1] is 1 and array_2[2] is 8?

```
array_2[1] = total_all / 10;
array_2[2] = total_all % 10;
```

But beware that C arrays are 0-indexed so you probably want

```
array_2[0] = total_all / 10;
array_2[1] = total_all % 10;
```

And why do you want to do that anyway?

Note that there are many other things wrong with your code, such as that you are summing the odd values and calling it the even sum, summing the even values and calling it the odd sum, providing parameters you never use, declaring functions to return `int` but not returning a value ...

Edit:

If you want the three low order digits of `total_all`, you can do this (reversing the order of the array):

```
array_2[0] = total_all % 10; // 1's place
array_2[1] = (total_all / 10) % 10; // 10's place
array_2[2] = (total_all / 100) % 10; // 100's place
```

If you want `n` digits, you can do this:

```
int temp_tot = total_all;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    array_2[i] = temp_tot % 10;
    temp_tot /= 10;
}
```

Try to understand the code, not just copy it, or you'll get stuck later.

Comment: Its part of a project for school. If the last digit of the sum is not a zero I need to subtract 10 from it. Its for some Bar code or UPC code.
But sometimes there might be 3 digits. I think the highest it can be is 108. How would i do array_2[2]?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to split the integer value into its digits as characters, try using itoa on the integer.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

"char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
Converts an integer value to a null-terminated string using the specified base and stores the result in the array given by str parameter."

Comment: Thanks Ill look into that and give it a try.

Comment: @JimBalter I am sorry for my careless.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int nSplit(int a[], int n){
    int p, d, i;
    p = (int)log10((double)n);//  n > 0

    d = n;
    for(i=p;i>=0;--i){
        a[i] = d % 10;
        d /=  10;
    }
    return p+1;
}

int main(void){
    int array[16] ={0};
    int len;
    len=nSplit(array, 18);
    {   //test print
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<len;++i)
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```